# How do I know the physical NFC antenna location in a device?

Tags: android, nfc, user-experience

I am trying to read NFC tags but the antenna location is different for different mobiles. Users typically don't know where exactly to tap the phone on a tag. So I want to know the location of the NFC antenna within my app. I would then want to notify the user through a some info graphic/image about how to best place their prone on a tag. Is this possible? How?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com).

Comment: @KlingKlang Could you please clarify your reasoning behind rolling back my changes? Also just to be clear: NFC is an RF communication interface (just like WiFi or Bluetooth, except for its more focused antenna beam). It's certainly not a sensor.

Comment: I reworded your post title to be more clear.

Comment: Samsung has a nice [NFC detection area overview](https://www.samsung.com/hk_en/nfc-support/#devicelist) for their phones.

Answer (score 4):

To know where the NFC antenna is located on the smartphone, here is a helpful description about this question :

First of all, not every smartphone has NFC although most of the modern devices do.

NFC stands for Near Field Communication.

If you are not sure if your smartphone is NFC-enabled or not, this list may help you: https://www.unitag.io/nfc/is-my-phone-compatible-with-nfc

Depending on which brand of smartphone and which model you are using, the NFC antenna may be located somewhere else on the device.

Below you will find links to the manufacturers’ homepages with more helpful information.  If you have any questions with regards to the NFC technology, please get in touch with the manufacturer of your phone.

- Samsung:
  The link below will guide you to Samsungs homepage where you can find the location of your NFC detection area with the help of pictures: https://www.samsung.com/hk_en/nfc-support/#devicelist
- Iphone:
  This link guides you to the different user guides for your iPhone in order to find the NFC antenna on your device: https://support.apple.com/

Please keep in mind that you need at least iOS 13.0 in order to be able to use the NFC antenna.

- Huawei:
  Please visit the supportpage, select your device model and you will find a sketch showing where to find the NFC antenna on your model in the start guide that can be downloaded: https://consumer.huawei.com/en/support/product/?tag=smart-phone&u=u
- Sony Xperia:
  If you have a Sony Xperia device you can use the following link https://www.sony.com/electronics/support/mobile-phones-tablets-mobile-phones and access the user guide for your device in order to find where the NFC antenna is located.
- Google Pixel:
  In order to find the NFC detection area for your Google Pixel phone you can follow the link below. You will find the location of the NFC antenna shown on sketches: https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/7157629
- Motorola:
  As the location of the NFC antenna may vary, please choose your model in the support section on Motorola’s website to get to these product specifications:
- https://support.motorola.com/in/en/home
- LG:
  On https://www.lg.com/hk_en/mobile you can  choose your smartphone model in the list. In the specifications you find sketches explaining the NFC position.
- HTC:
  To find the location of the NFC antenna of your HTC smartphone please visit the following page https://www.htc.com/support/ and can choose the model you are using and find the valid NFC information for your device.
- Nokia:
  Please check the manual for your model to see the exact location for your device: https://www.nokia.com/phones.

Some general information:

- Please keep in mind that smartphone cases can make it difficult to establish a NFC connection. If possible please remove the cases of your smartphone before starting to use NFC.
- The distance you should have between your smartphone and the device you would like - to establish a connection with, can be different for different mobile phones.
- No matter which smartphone model you are using, it is really important to hold the devices stable during the upload. Otherwise there is a risk of losing connection.
- If you have any questions with regards to NFC on your phone, always contact the manufacturer.
- In order to be able to use NFC on your phone your display may not be locked.
- Keep in mind that NFC needs to be enabled in the menu settings on some devices.

Finally it's arrived In Android 14, there new API added provided the physical location of the NFC antenna in Android :
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAntennaInfo
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since you asked this on SO, I assume you are trying to find a programmatic way to display the position in your app.

Unfortunately, there is no generic way to find the "sweet spot" (i.e. the antenna location or the spot where NFC tags are best placed on your phone). Android does not provide an API for this. So the only option woud be to get all the devices your users typically use (or dig into teardowns, etc. of those devices) and create a databse on your own.

Comment: Thanks a lot  Michael Roland

Comment: Hello, @Michael Roland there is new API provided by Android 14 which give this info. Please take a look on my Answer and update yours. Have a nice day